# Issues summing up array using for loop in swift

Tags: arrays, swift

I'm trying to iterate through an array and sum up all the values using generics like so:

```
func reduceDaArray <T, U>(a: [T], startingValue: U, summed: (U, T) -> U) -> U {

    var sum = 0

    for number in a {
        sum = sum + number
    }

    return sum
}

reduceDaArray([2,3,4,5,6], 2, +) //(22)
```

It's giving me the following errors:

`Binary operator '+' cannot be applied to operands of type 'Int' and 'A'` with regards to the line `sum = sum + number`

and

`Int is not convertible to 'U'` with regards to the line `return sum`

I know this is accomplished better with the reduce method, but I wanted to complete the task using iteration for this instance to get some practice. Why are these errors occurring? I never explicitly stated that T is an Int.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your `reduceDaArray()` function,

```
var sum = 0
```

declares an integer instead of using the given `startingValue`.
And

```
sum = sum + number
```

tries to add a generic array element to that integer, instead of using
the given `summed` closure.

So what you probably meant is

```
func reduceDaArray <T, U>(a: [T], startingValue: U, summed: (U, T) -> U) -> U {

    var sum = startingValue
    for number in a {
        sum = summed(sum, number)
    }
    return sum
}
```

which compiles and works as expected:

```
let x = reduceDaArray([2, 3, 4, 5, 6], 2, +)
println(x) // 22
let y = reduceDaArray([1.1, 2.2], 3.3, *)
println(y) // 7.986
let z = reduceDaArray(["bar", "baz"], "foo") { $0 + "-" + $1 }
println(z) // foo-bar-baz
```